# Active Record : Validation failed on create instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a `comment` instance. It returns me a validation error.

A `comment` `has one` `moderation` and include `reportable`. So you can do `moderation.reportable` and it return `comment`.

I want the `moderation` instance to be create when a new `comment` is created.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
      include Reportable

      after_create :create_moderation

      def create_moderation
        blog = self.blog
        self.create_moderation!(blog: blog)
      end
end


class Moderation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :reportable, foreign_key: "reportable_id", foreign_type: "reportable_type", polymorphic: true
...
end



module Reportable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_one :moderation, as: :reportable, foreign_key: "reportable_id", foreign_type: "reportable_type", class_name: "Moderation"
      has_many :reports, through: :moderation
end
```

> > Failure/Error: self.create_moderation!(blog: blog)
> >          ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
> >         Validation failed: Reportable must exist

**EDIT**

Trying to add :

```
belongs_to :reportable, foreign_key: "reportable_id", foreign_type: "reportable_type", polymorphic: true, optional: true
```

and get :

> > ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
> >            PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "reportable_id" violates not-null constraint
> >            DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1, Comment, null, 0, null, 2017-12-01 09:02:11.81419, 2017-12-01 09:02:11.81419, Blog, unmoderate).
> >            : INSERT INTO "moderations" ("blog_id", "reportable_type", "created_at", "updated_at", "blog_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"

Answer (score 1):

Try `optional: true` in association. Something like below:

`belongs_to :reportable, foreign_key: "reportable_id", foreign_type: "reportable_type", polymorphic: true, optional: true`

Refer [this](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html). The `optional: true` is introduced in Rails 5.

**EDIT**

```
after_create :create_moderation

def create_moderation
  blog = self.blog
  self.create_moderation!(blog: blog)
end
```

I see the two method names are same, i.e., after comment creation, the `create_moderation` is called which again calls the `create_moderation`. Can you try changing the name of the method maybe?

**ANOTHER SUGESSTION**

Can you change the method to

```
def create_moderation
  blog = self.blog
  Moderation.create!(blog: blog, reportable: self)
end
```

or

```
def create_moderation
  blog = self.blog
  comment = self
  comment.create_moderation!(blog: blog)
end
```

Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Still the same error `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:`

Comment: Can you please try the above?

Comment: Yes still the same even with your last suggestion :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  include Reportable

  before_create :create_moderation

  def create_moderation
    blog = self.blog
    self.build_moderation(blog: blog)
  end
end
```

Comment: I get this `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "moderations_reportable"
       DETAIL:  Key (reportable_type, reportable_id)=(Comment, 1) already exists.`